# Syncing a fork in Bitbucket, Branches and tags..how are they synced?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fork

I'm quite new to the whole forking "thingy".. I get the basics of the concept, but the part I don't get is: What happens to all the branches?

Lets say that I decide to fork a repository; the original repository adds a bunch of new branches, which I assume my fork won't be automatically updated with. Then if I decide to sync my fork with the original one, will this overwrite the newly created branches on the original? Or will they stay intact as long as I don't have a branch called the same thing located in the fork-repo? Is it the same regarding tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens to all the branches?

All the branches are located on your server (bitbucket in your case) once you have "published" (`git push`) them to the server.

---

> Lets say that I decide to fork a repository.. then the original repository adds a bunch of new branches (which I assume my fork won't get updated with automatically).

You are right on this, they will not be updated automatically.

---

> Then I decide to sync my fork with the original..
> will this overwrite the newly created branches on the original?

Nope, in order to get the latest updated you will have to `pull` the changes from the original repository. since pull is `fetch + merge` you will not "lose" your code. it will be merged together.

#### But

You cant publish your code to the original repo unless you are contributor to this repository. you have read access but not write access to it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're only taking [a copy of the repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/forking-a-repository-221449527.html#ForkingaRepository-BasicsofForking).  No branches or tags that you have in your fork will make their way over to the upstream copy of the repository if you don't explicitly make that happen.